# Sometimes can't connect to server

Tags: technical-issues, terraria, networking

I have a server hosted locally on my PC and both I and my wife can usually connect to it just fine, but sometimes, after we close the game and leave the server on, later **neither of us can join it unless we restart the server.**

Is this a known issue and is there a fix for that?

Comment: What does it say when you try and join? And in the console as well? Could you also post a log in pastebin and edit your question with it please?

Comment: It just keeps connecting and connecting without doing anything. The console mentions nothing as if no one is trying to connect. Not sure what log you're talking about as there is none in the game folder or documents.

Comment: The log, just like coping and pasting the console into a pastebin (minus personal information if there's any of course.) And what do you mean by 'connecting without doing anything.' Like you getting timed out?

Comment: It just says `Connecting to [IP]` forever. The server console shows the last message as `[Player_name] left.`. There is nothing unusual going on in console.

Comment: It might be a internet issue, have you checked that?

Comment: Not sure what to check, since the internet works and the server is within the home network. We connect through the local IP (192.168.2.11 and 127.0.0.1, if you care) and it connects again fine if I close the server (by typing `exit`) and run it again. It just seems to stop allowing us to connect after we have connected a couple of times and have left the server. First few times after a fresh server startup we both can connect just fine.

Comment: I realize this is an older question by now, but out of curiosity, are you using the automatic port feature of the server? I've been able to fix this problem by manually port forwarding from the router settings instead of letting the Terraria server do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

My friend and I had the exact same problem when playing! To solve it for us, he (the server owner) just set the max number of players to 8, instead of 2 as it originally was, and that allowed us both to leave and join without issue. Hope this works for you as well!

Comment: Are you sure that this was what fixed the problem and not just a coincidence?

Comment: I'm not positive if that was what it was, no. But it's worth a shot! It worked for us multiple times. Unfortunately neither of us have Terraria anymore so I cannot test it's validity again.